# O2 wireless box 2 change channel telnet

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, telnet

Anyone know how I can change the broadcast channel via telnet? The router is O2 wireless box 2.

Comment: Telnet? Meh! SSH is waaaay cooler! (And better, too because of its security and availability.)

Comment: hi, so you know the commands?